# Reading data from Google firestore with Python, daily reads count increases too fast

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I have a program reading data from a Google firestore database.
The database contains data for different users, and each instance of the program is supposed to read data only for a specified user.

The data is organized in this way:

```
UsersInfo (Collection)
|________User01 (document)
|________User02 (document)
...
|________UserN (document)
```

where each of the User documents contains an identifying ID.

The first time the program runs, it initializes the database and it looks for the right document containint the user info this way:

```
cred = credentials.Certificate(fcredentials_file.json)
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()


docs = db.collection(u'UsersInfo').stream()
user_found = False
current_user_document = ''
## find the right document, based on user_ID
try:
    for doc in docs:
        if doc.to_dict()['Userid'] == user_ID:
            current_user_document = doc.id
            user_found = True
            print(f"User found in document {current_user_document}")
            break
except:
    print("Impossible to find user in firestore!!!")
```

At this point, the correct document for the required user has been located.
This info is passed to other processes in the system, which routinely check this document to retrieve some info, something like:

```
doc_ref = db.collection(u'UserInfo').document(UserXX)
return doc_ref.get().to_dict()['some_field']
```

I was expecting that:

- during the initialization, the program checks all the UserXX documents in the collection (it's about 50 of them) -> 50 reads;
- everytime the other processes check the identified User document, it counts as another read.

However, the amount of reported reads is skyrocketing...I ran the system a couple of times today, each time it performed the initialization and the other components checked the User document 4 or 5 times...but now the Usage reports 11K reads!
Am I doing something wrong, or did I misunderstand what even counts as a read?

Comment: Look into queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one line alone immediately costs one read for **every** document in the collection:

```
docs = db.collection(u'UsersInfo').stream()
```

It doesn't matter what you do next - all of the documents are now read and available in memory.

If you are looking for only documents in the collection whose `Userid` field contains a specific value, you should [query the collection using a filter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries) on that field.

```
docs = db.collection(u'UsersInfo').where(u'Userid', u'==', user_ID).stream()
```